# Check if two parts of a string are the same with regex (PHP)?

Tags: php, regex

using a regular expression in PHP with preg_replace_callback how can I check if two parts of the pattern are the same?

```
preg_replace_callback('/Blah: (.*?), BLah Blah (.+?), (**String Here Must Be Same as First Match**)/s', create_function(), $subject);
```

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a backreference:

```
/Blah: (.*?), BLah Blah (.+?), \1/s
```

`\1` here denotes the first matched group.

Comment: Best place to go for more information on them is http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the link, I thought of adding a reference myself. :)

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but a comment reference will do. :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Guys! I've been trying to do this for the last 6 months lol!

Comment: You're welcome. Why did you wait 6 months to post in the first place? :)